# select records for this month ONLY

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

```
List<ActionPerformed> EndOfMonthPLUs = new List<ActionPerformed>();
List<ActionPerformed> AllPLUs = db.ActionPerformeds.ToList();

foreach (ActionPerformed ap in AllPLUs)
{
    if (ap.File_Name == "PLU" && ap.Status == "Processed" && ap.Date == ??)
    {
        EndOfMonthPLUs.Add(ap);
    }
}
```

I also want to add another query: && ap.Date == get all the files for this month.
So I have `string date = todaysDate.ToString("MMMM, yyyy");`

What now?

Comment: Is app.Date a DateTime or a string

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ap.Date` is a `DateTime`, you could check the month and year are identical:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

foreach (ActionPerformed ap in AllPLUs)
{
    if (ap.File_Name == "PLU" 
        && ap.Status == "Processed" 
        && ap.Date.Month == now.Month 
        && ap.Date.Year == now.Year)
    {
        EndOfMonthPLUs.Add(ap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare the Month and Year properties on the Date to those of the current DateTime:

```
var AllPLUs = db.ActionPerformeds.ToList();
var now = DateTime.Now;

var EndOfMonthPLUs = AllPLUs
    .Where(ap => 
        ap.File_Name == "PLU" && 
        ap.Status == "Processed" && 
        ap.Date.Month == now.Month && 
        ap.Date.Year == now.Year)
    .ToList();
```

I assume that the "db" variable refers to an Entity Framework context. If so, and if you don't have any further requirements for the list containing ALL the PLUs, you may wish to perform some or all of this filtering as part of the EF query.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not missing something, and your *ap.Date* property is a DateTime, could you just do this?

```
foreach (ActionPerformed ap in AllPLUs)
        {
            if (ap.File_Name == "PLU" && ap.Status == "Processed" && 
                ap.Date.Month == DateTime.Today.Month)
            {
                EndOfMonthPLUs.Add(ap);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
ap.Date.ToString("MMMM, yyyy") == date
```

is the answer you're looking for... alternatives could be

```
ap.Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && ap.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
```

or since you are using entities, a linq query could apply

```
var aps = from ap in AllPLUs
where ap.File_Name == "PLU"
&& ap.Status == "Processed"
&& ap.Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
&& ap.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
select ap
```

then

```
foreach(ActionPerformed ap in aps) { }
```